A "backward" complete induction
I see complete induction being written as


base case 
inductive step: assume the hypothesis is true for all $ k \le n $, prove it holds for n + 1


Would an inductive step of the kind:

Assume the hypothesis is true for all $ k < n $ prove that it holds for n

be valid as well?
Intuitively it seems just as an offset of 1. We merely assume the hypothesis holds for $ k \le n - 1 $ and prove for n. Because we are dealing with natural numbers by proving the inductive step from n-1 to n (offset by 1) we won't miss a case and the induction be true.
It "feels" logical to me but it made me think that we're looking "backward" instead of "forward" as in the classical approach of induction.
Even though this question baffled me in a lot of scenarios here is one example (which prompted this question now): 
I tried to prove the correctness of a recursive algorithm 'sum' to sum the keys of nodes of a binary tree that on each call for node x we would sum
sum(x.left_child()) + sum(x.right_child()) + x.key. 
I found it's more complicated to construct  tree of size n + 1 (nodes) from a tree of size n and then show the hypothesis holds. On the other hand, say we were given a tree of size n, it's quite easy to say each of the children's subtree consists of less than n nodes (without knowing its size) and so the assumption holds for both subtrees and we're done. Is it easier because I skipped a logical step or because this tool is better suited to this problem?
*I wrote the question in a math forum because it's mainly about the general form of induction

See Induction and variants. The two are the same: $k \le n$ means $k \lt n+1$.
